# Computing Minkowski Sum/Difference with Drake

Tags: drake

Problem: I want to compute the Minkowski difference of HPolyhedrons.

Reading the documentation of the Drake's [Geometric Optimization module](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__geometry__optimization.html) I found that:

> The geometry::optimization tools support:
>
> - Many advanced queries (intersections, Minkowski sum, set containment, etc).

However, searching for the "Minkowski" keyword in the documentation, or in the Github repository, I was not able to find some specific example or API to perform such operation. I was wondering whether the term "support" means that you have the ingredients to do it, but you should implement it yourself from scratch.

Are there some examples that can be helpful to understand how to approach the problem with the Drake framework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Other Drake developers likely have more details, but FYI https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/15543 might be related to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the news. It's quite fresh, I will monitor what they implement.
In the meanwhile, I have solved the problem by implementing my version of the operation.